# DD-WRT + Belkin router as Access Point = unreliable LAN

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt

Our apartment complex, like most, is bathed in wireless signals. One computer in the house cannot get a reliable WiFi signal from our router.

We had an old Belkin F6D4230-4 router lying around, and it supports Access Point mode, so I have it hooked up to a Switch which is in turn hooked up to the Router.

Now, there's no trouble with the internet connection while connect to either access point, but the LAN connection is horribly unreliable. Trying to stream video from my HTPC to my desktop PC (all on gigabit ethernet) works, but every so often it'll have to rebuffer. Unplugging the Belkin router from power fixes this problem.

Why would this be occurring? Is there anything in DD-WRT I can do to fix this?